# Plex Media Server And encFS

Tags: linux, docker, mount, plex, ecryptfs

I'm trying to Spin Plex Media server in Docker. And I want to mass my media as a Volume, but encrypted. Flow:
1. Mount volume from external storage on underlaying host.
2. mount volume to docker container as volume
3. encrypt data with encfs inside the docker
4. access data in Plex
5. Enjoy your media

The issue is than:
mount shows:
**encfs on /media type fuse.encfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions)**

Data is readable from unix level. BUT it is not readable for Plex (shows as emtpy folder only).

I susspect encFS or Plex itself not supporting Fuse mounts...

Any ideas? any flags for mounting? Any way to change mount type (can be other "proxy" container).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used encFS however, in case it helps or you're not aware, the default plex user (usually 'plex') must be an owner or in a group that is assigned to the media files.  In addition, if plex is showing an empty folder, it may be simply that the folder does not have read, write AND execute set i.e. chmod 775 (the folder needs the execute bit in order to list contents which is why 664 won't work).  I wrote a guide over on Tech-KnowHow for this yesterday, which outlines a few ways to get this done, if you need any help with it just leave me a comment and I'll see what I can do while it's all still fresh in my mind.

Good luck!

Direct link: https://www.tech-knowhow.com/2016/03/how-to-plex-permissions-linux/